# Working Gradle Spring Boot plugin + Distribution plugin configuration

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

I recently hit the following issue in Spring Boot 1.3.0M2 after upgrading from Gradle 2.2 to 2.5:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2679

> build in Gradle 2.3 runs more tasks than in Gradle 2.2

So I tried upgrading to Spring Boot 1.3.0M5 to get the fixes applied [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/867325095522ecd7f466ae7e95db490897e356b4) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/434f528e0a5810755d73be8d83e9927976ad8f97). However, with the following `gradle.build`:

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

applicationDistribution.with {
  // Exclude defaults in lieu of fat jar
  exclude { it.file in configurations.runtime.files }
  from("src/main/conf") { into "conf" }
}

distTar {
  compression Compression.GZIP
  extension "tar.gz"
}
```

My tarball no longer contains the `bootRepackage`'d jar and the scripts are not referencing correct main class.

Is there a way to get `bootRepackage`,`distTar` and generated shell scripts to work nicely together using Spring Boot 1.3.0M5 and Gradle 2.5?

Comment: Have you applied the application plugin? If so, the Boot plugin should [automatically set its main class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/springframework/boot/gradle/run/FindMainClassTask.java#L122-L124) so that the start scripts reference it correctly. If that's not happening then I think you've found a bug.